# Email signature question. Scaling on iPhone

Tags: mobile, iphone

I have created a email signature with a small logo embedded. Copied and pasted into signature box within Outlook for Mac.

The original is a PNG and larger than the size that is embedded (thinking this would allow the file to be scaled without loss of quality). When i receive the email sig on iPhone if i pinch to scale the email the signature logo pixelates (i.e: it does not scale up at all).

Assume this is because Outlook is embedding the file at the size i scale it to as opposed to the original PNG.

Is there a way to combat the potential of the logo being enlarged on iPhone and mobile devices, without loss of quality?

Comment: FYI: http://www.likeable.co.nz/3-reasons-why-your-logo-shouldnt-be-in-your-email-signature/